# Android - Trouble importing SlidingMenu library - SHA-1 Mismatch

Tags: android, slidingmenu

Okay I'm so close to throwing my computer out of the window. My head is boiling with rage lol

Im trying to Import the SlidingMenu lib into my brand new project. But I get an error: SHA-1 Mismatch. After a lot of digging, I found that I need to have only ONE `android-support-v4.jar` file in my `libs` folder. That's fine except...

1. Which `android-support-v4.jar` am I suppose to delete? The one in my Project or the one from inside the SlidingMenu library? And
2. Where am I suppose to **add external jar**? My project or the SlidingMenu library?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add to both but they have to match in terms of version. 
Pick the most updated version and replace in the respective lib folder.

Both android-support-v4.jar have to be the same version, otherwise you will have that conflict.

Comment: Okay, but my research showed that you delete one (don't know which one) and import the other ...v4.jar file via the add external jar... Is that incorrect or you can do it either way?

Comment: Both ways are viable. But if you want to use only one, I suppose you keep the version in the SlidingMenu library since you are "importing" from it and not the other way around.

Comment: I did: Import project as Library, then I deleted the .jar from MY project. Then I copied the .jar from the Library's \lib into my \lib and tried to run the project. Error: "Android library projects cannot be launched"

Comment: You are trying to launch a library project (sliding menu) and not your project. Be sure to "click" the right project before launching.

Comment: Solved that error. When I was importing the library, I checked the `IsLibrary` option for my project- thus declared my own project as a library... Woops